# P/Invoke Callback with variable arguments

Tags: vb.net, callback, dllimport, variadic-functions

A .h file contains the following signature:

```
typedef void (RTMP_LogCallback)(int level, const char *fmt, va_list);
void RTMP_LogSetCallback(RTMP_LogCallback *cb);
```

I would like to use it in VB.NET application, so I tried this way:

```
<DllImport("librtmp.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Shared Sub RTMP_LogSetCallback(cb As LogCallback)
End Sub

<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Delegate Sub LogCallback(level As LogLevel, message As String, args As IntPtr)
```

...

```
Private m_LogCallback As New LibRtmp.LogCallback(AddressOf LogCallback)
Private Sub LogCallback(lvl As LibRtmp.LogLevel, message As String, args As IntPtr)
    Console.WriteLine(message)
End Sub
```

`args` contains an integer that seems to be the arguments array pointer.

How can I get values from that array?

Comment: Variadic functions are not supported in VB.NET.  They are barely supported in C# with the undocumented __arglist keyword.  One approach is to pinvoke the vsprintf() function from msvcrt.dll, lots of ways to blow your leg off with that.  You should consider a helper DLL in the C++/CLI language instead.

Comment: Ok, I will use a DLL. By the way, can I expect to get something behind the pointer?